# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple Error

Tags: python, tuples

Just trying to make a tuple to add to make my main programming. Anyway this is my code-

```
print"I have a few things to finish my exam, but i might need more"
exam=("Brain","Computer","python")
print "The stuff i have are:"
for stuff in exam:
    print stuff
print"I still need my previous assignments!"
extra=("Assignments")
exam += extra
for stuff in exam:
    print stuff
```

---

I keep getting the can only concatenate tuple error. Anyone have a clue my issue/how to fix it? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: for the future, formatting your code will be make your code attempts easier to read so that people can clearly see what you're trying to do and where the problem is

Comment: Thanks alot! I tried to do so myself but couldnt get it working, just figured out now on how to format it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well that is because according to the [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

> Tuples are constructed by the comma operator (not within square brackets), with or without enclosing parentheses, but an empty tuple must have the enclosing parentheses, such as a, b, c or (). A single item tuple must have a trailing comma, such as (d,).

so if you do this to your code it has to work

```
extra = "Assignments",
```

or

```
extra = ("Assignments",)
```

Comment: how do you use this with the LIKE statement, getting the error because of LIKE

Comment: @PirateApp could you open a question, I think it's a different approach what you are trying to do.

Comment: `sum(tuple('a'), tuple('b'))` gives the same error - any ideas?  Thank you