# How to go about inputing str into tuples?

Tags: python

Hello I'm very new to Python and having some issues with understanding tuples. This code below gets this error: "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple"

Any idea the best way to do this? The code is supposed to take out only strings from the tuple "t" and then put them in a new tuple together.

Cheers!

```
    t = 1, 43.2, 'this is a string', 'what?','hello'
    t_new = tuple()

    for item in t:
         if isinstance(item, str):
              new_tuple_item = item
              t_new = t_new + new_tuple_item

    print('The filtered tuple is', t_new)
```

Comment: Try `t_new = t_new + (new_tuple_item,)` - although if you are going to keep growing the tuple, you might be better to use a list, and then append to it inside the loop - and possibly convert to a tuple at the end if required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203690/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-tuple-not-str-to-tuple-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange),

> Tuples are constructed by the comma operator (not within square brackets), with or without enclosing parentheses, but an empty tuple must have the enclosing parentheses, such as a, b, c or (). A single item tuple must have a trailing comma, such as (d,).

To fix this, you can use

```py
t_new = t_new + (new_tuple_item,)
```

This creates a new tuple that you can add to `t_new`

Comment: Thank you! I figured there were some way to make it into a tuple but couldn't figure it out.

To build on this: Anout the line earlier:

`new_tuple_item = item`

can't I make new_tuple_item a tuple already at that line and make it work thay way?

Comment: Yup! `new_tuple_item = item,` or `new_tuple_item = (item,)`. Both work.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter code:

```
t = 1, 43.2, 'this is a string', 'what?','hello'

t_new = tuple([item for item in t if isinstance(item, str)])

print('The filtered tuple is', t_new)
```

Output:

The filtered tuple is ('this is a string', 'what?', 'hello')

Comment: Thank you, that looks better indeed. I have a question as a beginner:

I get that it assigns the variable t_new as a tuple(), however why does there need to be []?

Also the `item for item` confuses me a bit. I get that it it's a for-loop that goes through all the instances of "t" if isinstance-conditions are met. 

Why are the variables item even needed in the first place to make this loop? Thankful for any help!

Comment: This Python construction is called "list comprehension" : Here we go through the tuple t (for item in t), item per item and construct a list from the items that comply the test condition (if isinstance).